# Tiempo agotado al intentar usar métodos de la clase Protection

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo este pequeño código para proteger en Google App Script (GAS)
usando como referencia la documentación [Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)

```
var obj     = {};

obj.source  = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

obj.source .getProtections( SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE )
           .filter( r=>r.remove() );

obj.range   = obj .source.getRange( "1:"+(obj.source.getLastRow()-3) );
protection  = obj .range.protect()
                  .setDescription("Daily Clear");

protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors())   #Problem Here!
//protection.removeEditor("test@gmail.com")         #Or Here!
```

Hasta aca, si no agrego las lineas de `protection.removeEditors( protection.getEditors() )` o `protection.removeEditor("test@gmail.com")` anda perfecto, pero cuando invoco para retirar editores, se quiebra el documento, arrojando:

> Exception: Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id [ID_SHEET].

Ya he usado `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` antes de `removeEditors() or removeEditor()` o en cada llamado a los metodos de la clase de forma desesperada, sin ningún resultado.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor agrega un [mcve]. Esto porque la pregunta no incluye suficientes detalles, por ejemplo, no está claro si estas usando un proyecto contenido en una hoja de cálculo o si es un proyecto independiente, si estás usando una perfil de Chrome donde hayas iniciado sesión con una única cuenta o estás haciendo uso del inicio de sesión múltiple, etc., etc.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he podido solucionar.

El tema esta que Google tiene un increíble delay para remover editores de un objeto Range.

### Mi solución

Apuntar a un objeto Sheet y con esta agregar los rangos editables. Solo funciona si tu libro trabaja por bloques ya que se bloquea toda la Hoja (Sheet) y no cada fila, dando una velocidad de respuesta mucho mas rápida.

Ejemplo:

```
function cron_protect()
{

var rows,protection;
var date = new Date();
var obj = {};
var emails = [a@gmail.com,b@gmail.com,c@gmail.com]

obj.source = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
obj.rowUltima = obj.source.getLastRow();

rows = obj.source.getRange("A:A").getValues();

obj.source.getProtections( SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE ).filter( r => r.remove() );
    
for(obj.row = 1; rows[obj.row][0] != "" && ![1,2,3].includes( rows[obj.row][0] ); obj.row++);

obj.row += 1;

obj.range       = "AX:A#-BX:B#-CX:C#-DX:M#"
.replace(/X/gi,obj.row)
.replace(/#/gi,obj.rowUltima)
.split("-")
.map( r => obj.source.getRange(r) )
;
    
protection      = obj.source
.protect()                                              //Aqui Protejo la hoja
.setDescription(date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes())  //Label descriptivo
.setUnprotectedRanges(obj.range);                       //Rango Editable

for (i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) protection.removeEditor( emails[i] );

}
```